# can't make images inline

Tags: html, css, web

I need to make my logo and a text box in one line. The logo must be on the left and text box in the middle.

My CSS is:

```
@charset "utf-8";

body {
background: url("../paveikslai/fonas.jpg") no-repeat top center;
margin: 0;
}

.linija {
background:url("../paveikslai/v_linija.png") repeat-x;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
}

.logotipas {
float: left;
display: inline;
margin: 0 15px;
}

.deze_tekstui {
margin: 0 50%;
}
```

And HTML is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/stilius/stilius.css'>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../paveikslai/favicon.ico">
<title>Minduvos Statyba</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="linija">
<div class="deze_tekstui">
<img src="../paveikslai/deze_tekstui.png">
</div>
<div class="logotipas">
<a href="../"><img src='../paveikslai/minduva.png' height='120px' width='234px' alt="Minduvos Statyba"></a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the logo to appear in a fixed position (top-left), you can't set it to `inline`.

```
.logotipas {
    margin: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

I recommend Firefox with Firebug, which makes on-the-fly experimentation very easy.

Comment: Same way. Create a text div with the same dimensions and positioning as your placeholder image. You may need to set scrolling. That light-grey box was correctly positioned in the header in my Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute position for the logo and margin auto for the text box, but you will have to define the width for it to work.

```
body {
background: url("../paveikslai/fonas.jpg") no-repeat top center;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
}

.linija {
background:url("../paveikslai/v_linija.png") repeat-x;
height: 150px;
padding: 10px;
margin: 0;
}

.logotipas {
display:block;
margin: 0 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 10px;
}

.deze_tekstui {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 500px;
}
```